# Objectify4 Order?

Tags: java, objectify

I upgraded my application to use Objectify4, but I can't get the ordering get working. 
Here is what I did: 
I have a class Offer which I want to query. This class is extended from Mail and from Model. The attribute for order should be the datetime which is indexed in the Mail-Class.

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.EntitySubclass;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Serialize;

@EntitySubclass(index=true)
public class Offer extends Mail {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6210617753276086669L;
    @Serialize private Article debit;
    @Serialize private Article credit;
    private boolean accepted;
...
}

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.EntitySubclass;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

@EntitySubclass(index=true)
public class Mail extends Model {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8417328804276215057L;
    @Index private Long datetime;
    @Index private String sender;
    @Index private String receiver;
...}

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Ignore;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

@Entity
public class Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5821221296324663253L;
    @Id Long id;
    @Index String name;
    @Ignore transient private Model parent;
    @Ignore transient private boolean changed;
...}


import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class DatabaseService {
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Model.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Mail.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Offer.class);
    }

    public static Objectify get() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }
}
```

and that's what I want to do:

```
Query<Offer> result = DatabaseService.get().load().type(Offer.class).order("-datetime");
```

Unfortunely, the result is always NOT sorted.

Has anyone a hint?

Answer (score 1):

At the low-level, this load operation has two parts:

- filter by ^i = Offer
- order by datetime desc

In order to make it work, you will need a multiproperty index like this:

```
<datastore-index kind="Model" ancestor="false">
    <property name="^i" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="datetime" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

However, you are almost certainly abusing the datastore by making all your entities extend a polymorphic Model.  You will have *many* problems in the future if you try to cram all of your entities into a single Kind; for one thing, practically every query will require a multiproperty index including the discriminator.

You can have a common base class, just don't make it the Kind.  Keep the inheritance hierarchy, but move the @Entity up to (say) Mail.  Offer can still have @EntitySubclass if you want a true polymorphic hierarchy there.

Read the objectify Concepts docs carefully and pick your Kinds carefully.